# Can BeautifulSoup (Python) include conditional coding?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, conditional-statements

How can I run code conditional upon the data I collect using BeautifulSoup and Python?
For example, if I want to collect data on a website only if the title of the page has a link and continue scraping to the next if it doesn't, how do I do that?
In other words, 'collect lines a and b if the title has a '3', but collect lines C and D if the title has a '4'

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: I don't understand the question, wouldn't standard `if .. else` construct suffice?

Comment: The if else is based on the content I am scraping so how do I read the content while I scrape it?

Answer (score 0):

```
if '3' in page.title:
   do_thing1(page)
elif '4' in page.title:
   do_thing2(page)
else:
   do_something(page)
```

I guess ....